# Changing Class file in InstalledApps directory of WebSphere 5.1

Tags: java, websphere

I have application deployed in the server long back. I don't have workspace setup procedure were i am not able to set up the project successfully into my RAD 7 Workspace. But i knew the Class file to be changed. I have changed and replaced in the Installed Apps Folder in Websphere server. But Application not working as expected.The changes are not affected. I modified one of the Jsp file. The changes are affected.

Verified After restarting the server as well.

Can any one help me what would be the problem.

I see there is one option called Export in Admin Console.

Answer (score 1):

I am afraid Websphere doesn't work like that.

The class files need to be loaded in memory of the deployment space (even after restart), but the jsp files are static can be loaded at run time.

I would do the following way:
(If I have the jar or the ear file)

1. Change the extension to zip
2. Open it with winzip or winrar
3. Locate the folder where your class file is located
4. Replace the file by a single drag and drop operation (it will replace automatically)
5. Change back the extension
6. Redeploy it in Websphere

Comment: But i don't have EAR File As well  in hand. Can i export the EAR file from server through Admin Console?